# Should we invert other ECG leads if aVR was positive?

Tags: cardiology, physiology, pathophysiology, electrocardiogram, cardiac-physiology

I would like to seek your kind guidance in understanding the right way of solving this question. (for the context, so far we only covered normal ECG and axis deviation)

The question displays all 12 ECG leads, and the first thing I noticed was that the aVR was positive, and all other limb leads were inverted except for Lead I which was positive. So I assumed that we have a limb lead reversal, whereby the negative electrode in this ECG is placed at the left side of the heart instead of the conventional positive electrode.

And attached below is my approach in solving this question, whereby I deduced that the axis is deviated to the right, however, all of my peers do not agree with my approach, which made me feel that I'm missing out on something.

The options for this question were:

A)RAD

B) Extreme RAD

C) Heart Rate is around 100bpm

D)ECG Shows bradycardia

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi. This seems to be a duplicate of your last question. You can edit that one to add new details (like the ECG tracing).

Comment: yes, you're right @Chris and @ iancampbell, thank you for correcting this! looking forward to hearing your opinion on this! :)